# Banner Navigation with Jquery/ JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i'm quite new to Js/Jquery. My knowledge is quite basic.

I have a home page banner which needs to slide left or right when clicking previous or next. I have spent some time checking google but i really don't know where to start.

```
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li><img alt="Banner 1" src="images/banner1.jpg"/></li>                             
        <li><img alt="Banner 1" src="images/banner2.jpg"/></li>             
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="banner-overlay">
    <div class="banner-nav">
        <img alt="Previous" src="/images/slide-prev.jpg"/>
        <img alt="Next" src="/images/slide-next.jpg"/>
     </div>
</div>
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery documentation for [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) and [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: I have yes, i don't understand how that can work sorry?

Comment: Try adding your JavaScript to your post to allow us to help you better. Your question is also quite vague. What exactly can we help you with?

Comment: Look at the `.animate()` demo where an square slides to the right. The `.click()` event listener will be helpful here to trigger the sliding.

Comment: Being new to Jquery i would not no where to start to manipulate that code to create a banner navigation.

Comment: If you are using flexslider, [read the documentation](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/), it should handle all of this for you

Comment: Brilliant! thanks Pete